# FsImage offline viewer

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have fsimage stored in my local directory, Using offline viewer command specified at 'https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/hadoop/hdfs_imageviewer.html' I have followed the instruction and executed the below command :
    hadoop oiv -i fsimage -o fsimage.txt
Output is :

```
16/06/24 08:09:18 INFO offlineImageViewer.FSImageHandler: Loading 24 strings
16/06/24 08:09:18 INFO offlineImageViewer.FSImageHandler: Loading 3027842 inodes.
16/06/24 08:09:32 INFO offlineImageViewer.FSImageHandler: Loading inode references
16/06/24 08:09:32 INFO offlineImageViewer.FSImageHandler: Loaded 0 inode references
16/06/24 08:09:32 INFO offlineImageViewer.FSImageHandler: Loading inode directory section
16/06/24 08:09:35 INFO offlineImageViewer.FSImageHandler: Loaded 1446245 directories
16/06/24 08:09:35 INFO offlineImageViewer.WebImageViewer: WebImageViewer started. Listening on /127.0.0.1:5978. Press Ctrl+C to stop the viewer.
```

But the fsimage.txt file is  of zero size, I have executed the command for XML format

```
hdfs oiv -p XML -i fsimage -o fsimage.xml
```

Which gives me fsimage.xml but I want this to be in '.txt' format, also In the output it says :

```
WebImageViewer started. Listening on /127.0.0.1:5978. Press Ctrl+C to stop the viewer.
```

Is there any UI available for accessing it, if yes how can we access it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use indented format which is delineate  the section of fsImage into separate levels of indentation.This also will be saved in txt format

[image]

You can refer this http://hadooptutorial.info/oiv-hdfs-offline-image-viewer/